# How to derive MRTS = 1/2 < 1 = w/r when production function equals √L+2K?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, economics

I'm finding the total cost of a production function. How do I derive the marginal rate of technical substitution (MRTS) solution as 1/2 < 1 = w/r, and why is it less than (<) as opposed to = w/r?

The first step in calculating the total cost is calculating the MRTS. I am calculating the MRTS using the following formula:

> [MRTS formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjn5I.jpg)

Therefore, I derived the MP of labor (L), substituting L for X.

> [MP of L](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RdVq.jpg)

Then, I derived the MP of capital (K), substituting K for Y.

> [MP of K](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a51xj.jpg)

Putting this into the original MRTS formula, I expect the answer to be  3/[2 sqrt (L+2K)] = w/r

> [Incorrect MRTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itr7G.jpg)

the given solution is however 1/2 < 1 = w/r.

> [Correct MRTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp2Qt.jpg)

Comment: This question belongs on economics stack exchange.

Comment: You were supposed to calculate $\frac{MP_L}{MP_K}$, which is clearly $1/2$, but you calculated $MP_L+MP_K$

Comment: Thank you, I miss little mistakes like that more often than I like to admit.